# Battery cannot charge fully

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power, power-management

I replaced battery on my MBA mid 2011 (A1369).

Here is the report by coconut(the same appears in system report):
[image]

I bought no name battery from china and changed it personally (here they ask about 250 EUR for replacement battery (labour and battery) what is for me crazy and I will not pay it).
However, it does not charge fully aa you can see on picture. The laptop gets more hotter and fan sometimes is going very noisy which before replacement did not make.
I went through forums and made all recommended actions - reset smc, pram. I charge sometime with 60W adapter. It made the same on maverics and now on el capitan as well.

Finally I ordered other battery from China which is on the way. However, as I could read here maybe the problem is in software. There is a little charging cycles done...

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The battery from he picture is 1583 days old !
And the status is "Check Battery" !
Th maximum charge is less than half the design capacity already !
The figure of 93.4% is how full it is of the maximum charge!
Coconut Battery is a very interesting app, but basically it reads what is in the SystemInformation. It does not measure itself.
This battery is dying/dead. REPLACE.
The problem is that third party batteries always are s**t. If you decide to buy such, you should only buy from a good supplier with a high reputation like OWC. Or a repair shop may have an used original Apple battery.